# Root category as a sub-category in default root category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I have a bunch of store, each one have a root category but they are match with sub category in my default root category. Is it possible if I create a new root category as a sub-category of the default root catalog? Or any extension (paid) can do that?

Please give me an advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Root category can only be in root :) Otherwise it is better to rethink your architecture.

Comment: @JevgeniBogatyrjov: Imagine, you are a B2B platform, now you offer a lot of merchant selling their products in your site. The merchants sell billion kinds of product, but you need their product display on your main website, you don't want to add product manually....

Comment: Still each store can only have one root category and then you can mark products to be shown in all stores ( can be automated ). And also you might want to look into some marketplace module like unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/

Comment: @JevgeniBogatyrjov: "Still each store can only have one root category and then you can mark products to be shown in all stores ( can be automated )." <<<< How?

Comment: Catalog -> Manage products -> New Product -> Websites. You can choose websites which a particular product will be visible on ( including all stores on the website ). Made a mistake in the previous comment about each store having a root category - actually each website has to have a root category.